# Web Forms send text from textbox to method onChange event

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm new in web forms. I need to send text from `aspx` page to server method using `onChange` in this `textbox`:

```
Email:
    <asp:TextBox ID="FilterAccountsTextBox" runat="server"/>
```

May anyone help me?

Comment: You don't need to _send_ the text. It's already there. Just reference `FilterAccountsTextBox.Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are. After you type on TextBox2 and leave it. The TextBox2.Text is post to Server (based on AutoPostBack attribute) to update Label1.

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="You type: "></asp:Label>
```

CS:

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "You type:" + TextBox2.Text;
}
```

Hope this help.